# How to use search on datatables with server-side processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

When working with datatables `server-side` proccessing. How does the search value being passed to the server? I've looked in the [doc](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side).

The datatable sends automatically the `draw`, `start` and the `length` to the server. Can and should I do something simular with the `search`? The documentation mention `search[value]` but I don't know how to interpretive it.

CLIENT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Home")';

    $('#example').dataTable({
        'searching': true,
        "paging": true,

        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "type": "GET"
        },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "name" }
        ]
    });
});
```

SERVER

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string draw, int start, int length, string search)
{
    var hugeDataArr = new object[100];
    var returnDataArr = new object[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < hugeDataArr.Length; i++)
    {
        hugeDataArr[i] = new
        {
            DT_RowId = i, 
            id = "id" + i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), 
            name = "nameæøå" + i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
        };
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        returnDataArr[i] = hugeDataArr[start + i];
    }

    JsonResult json = Json(new
    {
        draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw),
        recordsTotal = 100, // calculated field
        recordsFiltered = 50, // calculated field
        data = returnDataArr
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this, because it's never null but an empty string.

```
Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not supposed to use search as parameter.But it automatically is part of your query string.

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string draw, int start, int length)
{
     string search = Request.QueryString["search[value]"];
     // your code for search filtering

}
```

thanks
ravi

Comment: you can really do the params with Url request instead of params.

Answer (score 3):

## if you want to get value of serach box at server-side:

string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]").FirstOrDefault();

This will give you the value of search box.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the docs datatables passes a search array with two values.
search[value] is the search string which you'll need for filtering and search[regex] is just a boolean, expressing whether the search[value] should be interpreted as regex or just string.

If you're searching for values in a specific column the search string will be in columns[i][search][value]

Comment: So I have the parameter for the action wrong? It should't be `string search`but `string[] search`?

Comment: I've tryed string[] search now and it's still null.

Comment: The doc says: "To be applied to all columns which have searchable as true." I should add this right?

Answer (score 1):

If the `search[value]` parameter is always null then make sure you are using `POST` Ajax call on the client side and your action method of the controller is marked as `[HttpPost]`.

Clientside:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": url,
        "type": "POST"
    },
  //Other configurations
});
```

Server:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string draw, int start, int length)
{
     string search = Request.QueryString["search[value]"];
     // your code for search filtering

}
```